# Implement method return Volley request response

Tags: android, httprequest, android-volley

I am handling a  lot of internet request in my android application so I want to make a volley request inside a method and return the result of request in order to write less code So that every time I need to make a request I will call the method. Is this a good way or not? if so how to implement this method ?

Answer (score 1):

Having one point of entry and exit for all Network requests is not necessarily a bad implementation, though it does make your application tightly coupled and riddled with unnecessary parameters.

That said, It is not a 'wrong implementation'. Just, not scalable maybe.

Refer Google's official documentation [here.](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html) Scroll down to the heading `Example: GsonRequest`. That should answer your question.